# How to save a bitmap image to phone memory after applying mediaeffects to it ?

Tags: android, bitmap

I tried to apply the mediaeffects to my bitmap image object and it was successfully applied but now I want to save the image after applying the effects to it. How to do it ? I also referred other questions too but couldn't get appropriate answers.

Here is the code for it

```
public class HelloEffects extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    int mCurrentEffect;
    final Context context = this;

    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




        mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
        mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = R.id.autofix;
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

        // Load input bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.puppy);
        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Set texture parameters
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();
    }

    private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }

        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);

    }

    private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        }
        else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }
```